# i want to redeem token in solidity can anyone guide me how to redeem token see following fuction for redeem and guide me for redeem

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to buyback token in which i created redeem function which takes two argument

1. buyer address and
2. number of token which wants to return.
   it means buyer return number of token to seller. and then seller transfer ether from seller wallet to buyer which is calculated by (number of token/rprice

```
function redeem(address _buyer, uint256 vomoValue) public {  
    uint256 ethvalue = (vomoValue/625);
    uint256 actalEthValue = (ethvalue/100)*90 ether;
    console.log(actalEthValue,"actalEthValue");
    payable (_buyer).transfer(actalEthValue);
    // uint256 vomoValue = initialToken;
    balances[_buyer] -= vomoValue;
    emit Transfer(_buyer, msg.sender,vomoValue);
    balances[msg.sender] += vomoValue;
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code of all the smart contract?

Comment: how can i share

Comment: you can edit the question

Comment: I don't really understand the question. what this mean? ---> after that return ether buyer from seller wallet which is calluted by (num token divide price)

Comment: it means if buyer wants to redeem there number of token(eg. sales return in general term) and that should transfer in seller account and return their eth to buyer wallet respectively

Comment: so:
buyer send ether to seller
seller send token to buyer
?

Comment: no buyer return token and seller send ether to buyer(sales return)